# VBA code to hide/unhide rows based on single cell value

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

I am not quite understanding why my code is not working. Essentially in cell B5 I have two options, "calc_1" and "calc_2", which the user can select via drop-down.

I want rows 6 to 29 to show and rows 30 to 53 to be hidden if calc_1 is selected, and vice-versa for calc_2. Below is the code that I wrote:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    If Range("B5").Value = "calc_1" Then
        Rows("6:29").EntireRow.Hidden = False
        Rows("30:53").EntireRow.Hidden = True
        

    ElseIf Range("B5").Value = "calc_2" Then
        Rows("6:29").EntireRow.Hidden = True
        Rows("30:53").EntireRow.Hidden = False

    End If

End Sub
```

When I run this code, only rows 6 to 29 are showing no matter what selection I make. I'm not sure what I'm missing here.

Comment: I think the syntax to use is `Rows("6:29").Hidden = False`.

Answer (score 0):

### Worksheet Change & Intersect

- The code was running on each change in the worksheet. You need to restrict it to run only when a change has happened in cell `B5`...

  ```
  If not Intersect(Range("B5"), Target) Is Nothing Then
      ' do your stuff
  End If
  ```

  ... or like in the code:

  ```
  If Intersect(Range("B5"), Target) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub

  ' do your stuff
  ```
- EntireRow is redundant in this case as harrymc mentioned in the comments.

```vb
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    
    Dim iCell As Range: Set iCell = Intersect(Range("B5"), Target)
    If iCell Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    
    If iCell.Value = "calc_1" Then
        Rows("6:29").Hidden = False
        Rows("30:53").Hidden = True
    ElseIf iCell.Value = "calc_2" Then
        Rows("6:29").Hidden = True
        Rows("30:53").Hidden = False
    'Else ' do nothing
    End If

End Sub
```

Optionally, you can use `Select Case` instead of `If ElseIf`.

```
Select Case iCell.Value
Case "calc_1"
    Rows("6:29").Hidden = False
    Rows("30:53").Hidden = True
Case "calc_2"
    Rows("6:29").Hidden = True
    Rows("30:53").Hidden = False
'Case Else ' do nothing
End Select
```